# Magento - accessing a partial refunded order line

Tags: php, magento

I've created a custom export of order and order lines which basically captures all order states, status, price changes etc.

I've run into a little problem with Credit Memos. 
What I would like to do is, when an order line from a multiple line order has been refunded, I would like to just add a comment into the database to say that this order line has been refunded.

I just want to be able to access the the order line that has been refunded but can't seem to figure it out.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See if you can insert this code in some credit memo create after observer or if not then by overriding create controller for credit memo.

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementID);
// Add the comment and save the order
$order->addStatusToHistory($order->getStatus(), 'Another new comment', false);
$order->save();
```